# changes in MainStoryboard doesn't effect the app

Tags: ios, storyboard

I've made a few changes in my app, the changes are in the MainStoryboard.
When I click run, the changes doesn't appear in the application. What is the problem?

Example: I add a label in the main screen and when I click run I can't see this label.

Comment: Are you sure the build succeeds? Do you run in simulator or device? What version? Dd you restart xcode? Did you try 'reset contents and settings'? Did you do a clean build?

Comment: Does your app have multi-language? If so, make sure you are changing the correct Storyboard... I've made that mistake before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue after I started internationalizing my project.  I had one storyboard and two strings files.  However, when I hoked around in the project using Terminal, I found that the old version of the storyboard was still there, so I moved it out.

All that said, to fix the issue I had to physically delete the app from the device/simulator and run it again.  Performing a clean build didn't work for me.

If performing a clean build and deleting the app from the device/simulator doesn't work, then have a look inside your project directory for any rouge storyboard files.

Comment: Excellent!  Which bit solved it?  Deleting from the device or deleting a rogue storyboard? (or both :-)

Answer (score 0):

clean your build folder. Complete remove all the build that are already install in your device or simulator.

I have also the same problem, actually I have two build install in the simulator with different identifier that is causing the problem